# Net magnetic field at a point

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields

Given 5 wires ( $w_0, w_1,w_2,w_3,w_4$) all separated equally by a distance ($r$) from one another like this diagram:

[image]

Applied a voltage two each wire individually and current flows like so:

[image]

Also, a magnetic field is created for each individual wire like so:

[image]

**NOTE: Field lines are not drawn to scale just an idea of the direction, if run with a simulator(which unfortunately is not functional for me now) it would show it better and the result.**

I'm not sure what the net magnetic field would be at the given points($a,b$) here:
[image]

In this case, the set-up is in a way that $B_1$ = $B_0 + B_2$ Likewise, $B_3$ = $B_0 + B_4$

Comment: Simply use superposition principle of five different magnetic fields. The direction should be south-west because in the absence of the central wire the direction is downward (by symmetry).

Comment: @Benjamin I did, my thought is the net magnetic at point A and B is zero, because the fields are opposing, at point A for example the two fields of $B_0$ and $B_2$ add up, and since the net is equal(and opposing) to $B_1$ it would cancel out. Likewise with point B, however, I'm not sure.